# Insert data to firebase -Android - and check specific properties

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I need to insert lesson object to firebase, so I put here the onData change section of code.
First of all I get data snapshot and insert the lessons that I have in firebase, after that I scan the List of Lessons and check:
if the date and time **exist** in the firebase in *any Lesson* so I  do something else I insert the lesson object to firebase .
The main problem is :
when I insert the details of the lesson and press add, the lesson enter to the firebase twice minimum, and if I try another insertion the program enter to infinite loop .
will be happy for any help !

```
   ArrayList<Lesson> existLesson=new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
    int counter=0;
public void getLessons(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        //insert the lessons to "existLesson" arrayList
        for (DataSnapshot keyNode : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                keys.add(keyNode.getKey());
                Lesson lesson = keyNode.getValue(Lesson.class);
                existLesson.add(lesson);
                Log.i(tag, "data : " + lesson.getSubject());
        }//for
}

    int flag=1;
    @Override
    public void addLesson(final String subject, final String topic, final String date, final String time) {


        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    getLessons(dataSnapshot);

                    //Check if date and time is busy
                    for (Lesson lessonToCheck : existLesson) {
                        if (lessonToCheck.getDate().equals(date) && lessonToCheck.getTime().equals(time)) {  
                            flag = 0;
                        } else {
                            flag = 1;
                        }
                    }//for
                    if (flag == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(LessonDetails.this, "date exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // Check empty lessons
                        nearestLessons(existLesson, date, time);
                    } else {
                        if (flag == 1) {
                            String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                            Lesson lesson = new Lesson(subject, topic, date, time, id); //create lesson
                            Toast.makeText(LessonDetails.this,
                                    subject + " - " + topic + " - " + date + " - " + time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            mDatabase.child(id).setValue(lesson);
                        } //add lesson to DB
                    } //else

         Log.i(tag,"end");
            } //onDataChange
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `you're adding a listener to the data at`. This listener will immediately read the data and call your `onDataChange`, and then continues to listen for updates to the data.

For each update to the data, it calls your `onDataChange` again. And since you're updating the data inside `onDataChange`, this ends in an endless loop of `setValue`->`onDataChange`->`setValue`->`onDataChange`->...

To fix this, you'd typically use `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` instead, as this only gets the value once and doesn't continue listening for changes.

So something like:

```
mDatabase.addForListenerValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            getLessons(dataSnapshot);

            //Check if date and time is busy
            for (Lesson lessonToCheck : existLesson) {
                if (lessonToCheck.getDate().equals(date) && lessonToCheck.getTime().equals(time)) {  
                    flag = 0;
                } else {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }//for
            if (flag == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(LessonDetails.this, "date exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Check empty lessons
                nearestLessons(existLesson, date, time);
            } else {
                if (flag == 1) {
                    String id = mDatabase.push().getKey();
                    Lesson lesson = new Lesson(subject, topic, date, time, id); //create lesson
                    Toast.makeText(LessonDetails.this,
                            subject + " - " + topic + " - " + date + " - " + time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mDatabase.child(id).setValue(lesson);
                } //add lesson to DB
            } //else

        Log.i(tag,"end");
    } //onDataChange
})
```

---

Note that, since you're updating the data based on its current value, there's a chance that another user may be doing the same operation at almost the same time. If this can lead to conflicting updates in your use-case, consider [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) which combines the read and write from your code into a single (repeatable) operation.