# Firebase push() method create multiple key continuously

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a random key in a child  on button click and insert data in this key

but When I click on the button  it creates multiple keys with the same data  and it goes continuously  till I close the app in the background

above problem is in `postreview()` method in my code i call this method on the button clcik

```java
  
    public class DisplayStory extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Tittle;
    WebView webView;
    String story;
    String storyname;
    String catagory;
    String TAG = "display";
    DatabaseReference storyref;
    DatabaseReference ratingref;
    RatingObject ratingObject;
    // review stuff
    RatingBar user_ratingBar;
    EditText comment_EditText;
    EditText senderName_editText;
    Button submit;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_story);
        Tittle = findViewById(R.id.TITLE);
        webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
        // review stuff
        user_ratingBar = findViewById(R.id.ratings_to_submit);
        comment_EditText = findViewById(R.id.comment_to_submit);
        senderName_editText = findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.submit_btn);

        storyname = getIntent().getStringExtra("tittle");
        catagory = getIntent().getStringExtra("catagory");

        Log.d(TAG,"storyname "+storyname);
        Log.d(TAG,"storyname "+catagory);

        Tittle.setText(storyname);
        storyref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(catagory).child(storyname);
        ratingref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(catagory).child(storyname).child("rating");
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PostReview();
            }
        });


        storyref.child("story").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    story = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                    webView.loadData(story,"text/html", "UTF-8");
                    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    webView.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
                    Log.d(TAG,"story exist ");
                    Log.d(TAG,"story "+story);

                }
                else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"no story exist ");

                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });




    }

    public void PostReview(){
        final String name,comment;
        final float rating;
        name = senderName_editText.getText().toString();
        comment = comment_EditText.getText().toString();
        rating = user_ratingBar.getRating();
        ratingref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                 ratingObject =
                        new RatingObject(name,comment,rating);
                ratingref.push().setValue(ratingObject);



            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no need to attach a listener in your `PostReview` method since you don't use any data from the `dataSnapshot` in there.

So in that case, the code can be much simpler:

```
public void PostReview(){
    final String name,comment;
    final float rating;
    name = senderName_editText.getText().toString();
    comment = comment_EditText.getText().toString();
    rating = user_ratingBar.getRating();
    ratingObject = new RatingObject(name,comment,rating);
    ratingref.push().setValue(ratingObject);
}
```

This will also solve the endless loop, which was caused by calling `setValue` inside the `onDataChange` of a listener added with `addValueEventListener`. For a longer explanation of that, see:

- [Changing value in Firebase results in infinite loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62844510/changing-value-in-firebase-results-in-infinite-loop/62844732#62844732)
- [Insert data to firebase -Android - and check specific properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62803569/insert-data-to-firebase-android-and-check-specific-properties/62804982#62804982)